# How do you Implement Landscape Launch Screen for iPhones?

Tags: ios, landscape, launch

How do you implement landscape launch screens for iPhones? I've seen the "plist duplicate" posts and added the arrays they suggested to my plist, and added my launch images to my xcassets file which is set as my launch image so it shows as just a black screen. when removing assets catalogue, theres a bar of black on both the left and right side of the screen the whole time the app is running. Also, if its not done through cassettes, what do you name the images and where do they go? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking about launch *images* or launch *screens*?

There's no such thing as a landscape launch *image* for iPhone. You provide a normal launch image in portrait, and if the app launches in landscape, that launch image is automatically turned on its side.

But in this day and age it would be best to forget about launch *images* and use a launch *screen*, a *xib* file or storyboard. It knows nothing of orientation and doesn't need to know anything: you just configure its appearance using autolayout to match whatever the circumstances turn out to be.

Comment: Well, I was talking about launch images, in the fact that the one I've rotated 90 degrees doesn't show up when launching in landscape on the simulator. How would you go about making an xib file? Also, are they any different then storyboards? Sorry if these are dumb questions, I'm not very used to Xcode, I used Codea to develop my app and am just getting ready to publish it, I'm pretty good in Lua, but not much else :)

Comment: "the fact that the one I've rotated 90 degrees doesn't show up" Did you read my answer? Don't do that. You don't rotate it; the system will.